# Error 1045 access denied from DMS source database

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I got below error while try to migrate database from Mysql enterprise version 8.0.23-commercial even I grant all REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE to migration user I still got this error and also turn on binlog

[SOURCE_CAPTURE  ]E:  Error 1045 (Access denied for user 'migration'@'IP' (using password: YES)) connecting to MySQL server 'IP' [1020414]  (mysql_endpoint_capture.c:297)

2021-09-28T17:46:20 [SOURCE_CAPTURE  ]E:  Errors in MySQL server binary logging configuration. Follow all prerequisites for 'MySQL as a source in DMS' from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MySQL.html or'MySQL as a target in DMS' from
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.MySQL.html  [1020414]  (mysql_endpoint_imp.c:778)

If migrate full load only via this endpoint it successfully this error found when full load + on going migration

Answer (score 2):

To replicate database migration must use TCP/IP port. You should check this port and run database migration again.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue while working on AWS DMS RDS mysql to MSK Kafka data migration. I resolved by configuring mysql source endpoint with Secure Socket Layer (SSL) mode  `verify-ca`.

To get a certificate bundle that contains both the intermediate and root certificates for all AWS Regions, download from https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem.

You can valuvate your error in following doc
https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/07/05/fixing-a-mysql-1045-error/

Comment: I did this but I'm still getting the same error.